# how to assign 2 d array to pointer to an array in

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, initialization, implicit-conversion

I have a pointer to an array (2d array). I like to assign 2d array to a pointer

```
  int (*p)[2]={{1,2}};//SegFault
  int (*p)[2]=(int **){{1,2},{3,4}}; //should it be same as above? but also causing segFault/
  int (*p)[2]=(int[][]){{5,4},{5,6}};//should it be same as above two? but also causing segFault
```

And how can I access the values. should it be correct `*(*(p)` to access of first array and first value. // Willl it also work `p[0][0]` I think so, but please clarify that are these access methods are purely how C is designed or Is there any memory matters if I use `*(*(p))` or `p[0][0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This declaration

```
int (*p)[2]={{1,2}};
```

is syntactically incorrect. Pointers are scalar objects and they may be initialized by a single expression optionally enclosed in braces.

In this declaration

```
int (*p)[2]=(int **){{1,2},{3,4}}
```

you are trying to use a compound literal but again the initialization is incorrect because an object of the type `int **` is a scalar object and my be initialized by a single expression.

In this declaration with a compound literal

```
int (*p)[2]=(int[][]){{5,4},{5,6}};
```

there is used an incorrect type specifier `int[][]` for a two-dimensional array because the size of elements of the array is unknown. You could write for example

```
int (*p)[2]=(int[][2]){{5,4},{5,6}};
```

That is you need to have an array that you will assign to a pointer. If you do not have such an array you can use a compound literal. For example

```
int (*p)[2] = (int[2][2]){{1,2},{3,4}};
```

or

```
int (*p)[2] = (int[][2]){{1,2},{3,4}};
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 2 };
    
    int ( *p )[N] = ( int[N][N] ){ { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", p[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    int a[N][N] = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
    p = a;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", p[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    int b[N] = { 1, 2 };
    p = &b;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", ( *p )[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 
3 4 

1 2 
3 4 

1 2
```

Comment: in `int (*p)[2]=(int **){{1,2},{3,4}}` u said `Pointers are scalar objects and they may be initialized by a single expression optionally enclosed in braces.` does this mean I can do `int (*p)[2]=(int**)1` or `int (*p)[2]=(int **){1}` or `int (*p)[2]=(int **)(1)` or `int (*p)[2]=(int **)'c'` or `int (*p)[2]=(**int)"c"` are they all correct

Comment: what do u mean by `compound literal` as in `you are trying to use a compound literal`?

Comment: @user786 Syntactically there is incorrect this declaration int (*p)[2]=(**int)"c". But semantically neither declaration makes a sense.

Comment: @user786 In my answer there are examples of using compound literals as initializers.

Comment: @user786 For example in this declaration int x = ( int ){ 10 }; there is a compound literal ( int ){ 10 } that is used as an initializer of the variable x. That is the compiler creates two object of the type int. The first one is unnamed object of the type int that corresponds to the compound literal and the second one is the object x that is initialized by the unnamed object that corresponds to the compound literal.

Comment: why `int (*p)[9]=(int **)('c');printf("%c\n",(*p));` works and this `int (*p)[9]=(int **)"c";printf("%c\n",(*p));` does not work?can u please tell me

Comment: @user786 For the both construction the compiler should issue a message. There is no implicit conversion from the type int ** to the type int ( * )[9].

Comment: what that will represent `int ( * )[9]`

Comment: @user786 It is a pointer. You have too many questions. You should read a book on C.

Comment: thanks for your help. I will. but just last thing is u wrote something like `int (*p)[1]=(int[][3]){{1,6,8},{1,2,9}};` u are doing something like `(int[][3])` is this same as `int (*p)[1]=(int[1][3]){{1,6,8},{1,2,9}};`

Comment: @user786 I am sorry I have not understood your question Again int ( * )[1] and int ( * )[3] are not compatible pointer types.

Answer (score 2):

- `{{1,2}};` is an array initializer, not an array. So the code is invalid C - you can't initialize a pointer like that. It's the wrong type `int` and the wrong number of initializers.
- `(int **){{1,2},{3,4}};` is a compound literal of type `int**`. But again, the initialization of a pointer like this is invalid C.
- `(int[][]){{5,4},{5,6}};` is an array of incomplete type. It can't be initialized. So this too is invalid C.

All of your problems originate from ignoring compiler warnings. In case of gcc-like compilers I strongly recommend to change your settings to `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`. Then you'll get compiler errors when you write invalid C, instead of just warnings.

To answer the question, the correct way is:

```
int (*p)[2] = (int[2][2]){ {1,2}, {3,4} };
```

This creates a local scope 2D array with the same scope as the pointer `p`. This is equivalent to:

```
int arr[2][2] = { {1,2}, {3,4} };
int (*p)[2] = arr;
```

Comment: can I dynamically assign values to `int (*p)[2]` I wont mind if I use `malloc`

Comment: @user786 Yes this gives read-write memory. The malloc equivalent would be `malloc(sizeof(int[2][2]));`

Comment: Can somehow i extend the size of pointer to 2d array with multiple calls to `malloc`?

Comment: @user786 You should be able to call realloc with the old pointer type as parameter, then assign the result to a different pointer type with another width. For the internal type rules of C to make sense, the compiler will have to forget about what "effective type" a certain object had before realloc(). In practice these rules are so poorly written in the standard that it becomes a quality of compiler implementation thing.